# resignfirstresponder crashes my ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

I am new to IOS and can't seem to get this to work , I have an input filed on my app,from which I want to hide the keyboard whenever the user either presses return or the associated button (searchGo)

The following is my code :

mainViewController.h

```
 @interface kepnMainViewController : UIViewController <kepnFlipsideViewControllerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    MKMapView *_mapView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *searchBox;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *searchGo; 
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *searchNearby;
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKMapView *_mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MapAnnotation *annotation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *flipsidePopoverController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKAnnotationView *annotationView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem *searchGo; 



- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)searchGo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showNearby:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)searchBoxReturn:(id)sender;

- (void) setPlaceMarker: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) coord :(NSString*) title :(NSString*) subtitle; 
@end
```

Appropriate .m snippet

```
-(IBAction)searchGo:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sender object %@",sender); 


         [sender resignFirstResponder];


    NSLog(@"search button pressed and textbox = %@",searchBox.text); 


}



-(IBAction)searchBoxReturn:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"search box return "); 

    [sender resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question but what am I doing wrong.??

Comment: Do you connect your properties in Interface Builder (IB) to your GUI elements, or do you have a programmed view?
However, what you can check whether your sender is a kind of UIResponder ( if ( [sender isKindOf: [UIResponder class]] ) ... ) and if it is allowed to resign the first responder ( if ( [(UIResponder*)sender canResignFirstResponder] ) ... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItem` isnt an `UIView` and therefore definitely not an `UIResponder`. Instead, it's a subclass of `NSObject`, which doesn't respond to `- (void)resignFirstResponder`.

(solution: remove the `[sender resignFirstResponder];` lines)

Comment: Thanks - so is there a way to get a UIBarButton to do this. Or more importantly why does UITextField which is a UIView fail?

Comment: You don't need to get an `UIBarButtonItem` to do this, since it's "deselected" immediately after you release your finger. You don't need to resign the first responder anymore.

Comment: In order to hide the keyboard, use `[searchBox endEditing:YES];` :)

Comment: Thanks very much, that work answer (accepted answer) - WOuld you be able to point me in the right direction for making it work from pressing return on virtual keyboard

Answer (score 1):

So if your view is manually programmed than you might add the following check to your code:

```
 if ( [sender isKindOf: [UIResponder class]] == YES && [(UIResponder*)sender canResignFirstResponder] == YES )
     [sender resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide keybord on button tap assuming your searchBox is current responder than you should write

```
[searchBox resignFirstResponder]; // This will close keyboard
```